# How to find out if a pillow is unhealthy and bad for neck

Tags: personal-care, sleeping

I been having neck pain and sleepless night and I wonder if my pillow are beyond it’s age. So how does one find how long pillow are useful before it need changing and what are signs of unhealthy pillow.

Answer (score 2):

Here are advices to get to know which pillow you should use (and therefore reduce neck pain)

All you need to do is pair the **right pillow with your sleeping position**:

- **Side sleepers** require a pillow that’s firm enough to support the head and neck’s alignment with the spine, while still comfortable enough to fall asleep on. Good options include firm or extra firm [pillows made of memory foam](https://www.tuck.com/best-memory-foam-pillows/) or [natural latex](https://www.tuck.com/best-latex-pillows/) foam that provide sufficient give and sink in response to the weight and pressure of your head. Alternately, an orthopedic or contour pillow with a depression for the head area and extra padding under the neck can provide proper support.
- **Back sleepers** also require a firm pillow that keeps their neck straight with their spine. Contour loft pillows with divots for the neck and head are a recommended option.
- [**Combination sleepers**](https://www.tuck.com/best-mattress-combination-sleepers/) that transition between the side and back should choose pillows with a dent in the middle.
- **Stomach sleepers** need a thin, soft pillow. However, even with the right pillow, stomach sleepers may still (and often do) experience neck pain because they’re moving their head to the side and out of alignment with the spine.

*For further informations please see [This article](https://www.tuck.com/can-soft-pillows-cause-neck-pain/)*

Comment: I use [this](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/textiles-rugs/pillows/r%C3%B6lleka-memory-foam-pillow-art-90269838/) one . It had playeed important role getting me full sleep.

Comment: Alright, glad to hear that you found the one that suit you ;)

Comment: but generally how long a pillow should be replace?

Comment: I am afraid there’s no exact science to determine when it's time to replace your pillow. But you can easily keep it from few years to an entire life. It depend on the quality.

Answer (score 0):

To test, try this:

1. Buy a new pillow.
2. Set your current pillow aside. Use the new pillow for 2 or 3 days.
3. If your neck pain and sleepless nights go away, then throw out your old pillow and keep using your new one!
4. If your neck pain continues and you still can't sleep, then something else is the cause. You can start using your old pillow again, and store your new pillow until your old one is REALLY unusable. (Then start looking for other things that could be causing your pain and sleeplessness.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have had neck pain from a crick in the neck or other slight injury, any pillow might seem to have been the culprit for your neck pain. You can fold your pillow (the flatter the better!) lengthwise to support the back of your neck ( or place a small soft towel in the curvature of the back of your neck) and that should help prevent neck pain while sleeping. It has for me! Feel better!